# Making a call to a method without importing a particular project

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am making some modifications to already existing code and what I need to do is call a method from class A of project X into a method of class B of project Y, without explicitly importing the class A into class B. Creating an import of class A in class B will create a cycle in the build path, which I have to avoid at all costs. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it possible for you to refactor and move the method, or even all of class A?

Comment: @Romojr50: I'm afraid that is not possible. Although class A is newly created, it logically has to reside in project X (based on product implementation).

Comment: @CodeNewbie never say it is not possible, you cannot know it (having your name). It is possible by using Reflection, you just install the .jar file in the search path. And there are more posibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at **Dependency Inversion** which is basically a principle/technique to manage the directionality of dependencies by using abstract classes or interfaces along with your concrete implementations:

[Here's a beginner's tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver) (the examples are in C# but Java doesn't differ much)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by an `Interface` (to call the method), a factory pattern to create the object which method you want to call, and or `Reflection` which allows to create objects and call methods for which you only know the name (e,g given in an config file).
 However try it first without reflection.